# Soft Access Point/Client Connect using wpa_supplicant with 2.4/5Ghz channels

Tags: linux, wifi, yocto, wpa, wpa-supplicant

This is a weird one. Let me start with that.

I am currently working on a Yocto embedded linux board from Digi, if that matters. I have just managed to, through use of dnsmasq and wpa_supplicant, allow other devices to connect to the board.

My current question is this: Can I use the 5.0 Ghz channel for allowing other devices to connect, and the 2.4Ghz channel to allow for the board to connect to other wifi access points?

My configurations:

```
#dnsmasq.conf 
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.200,2h

#interfaces
auto wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
wpa_driver nl80211
wpa_conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

#wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
fast_reauth=1
update_config=1

#Soft AP Mode
ap_scan=2
network={
    ssid="mySSID"
    mode=2
    frequency=2412
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RNS
    pairwise=CCMP
    psk="MySecret"
}
```

Does anyone has an idea (or better yet, an improved version of what I'm doing) of how to get it to do this?

Comment: Could it be the case that you also have hostapd somewhere in that equation?

Comment: I have hostapd installed but I'm not using it. I tried using it but it wasn't behaving correctly and was I was not able to connect. My tablet just said 'Saved' whenever I attempted to connected. I was following the Yocto/Wireless guidelines.